# Matlab: How to convert nested far loop into parfor

Tags: performance, matlab, parallel-processing

I am having problems with the following loop, since it is taking too much time. Hence, I would like to use parallel processing, specifically parfor function.

```
P = numel(scaleX); %  quite BIG number
sz = P;
start = 1;
sqrL = 10; %  sqr len
e = 200;
A = false(sz, sz);

for m = sz-sqrL/2:(-1)*sqrL:start
    for n = M(m):-sqrL:1
        temp = [scaleX(m), scaleY(m); scaleX(n), scaleY(n)];
        d = pdist(temp, 'euclidean');
        if d < e
            A(m, n) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Can anyone, please, help me to convert the outer 'far' loop into 'parfor' in this code?

Comment: Is your code working or not? What errors are produced? Be specific!

Comment: Are you sure you need a `parfor`?  Though difficult to trace through, it looks like you can vectorize this code.  You certainly don't need to call `pdist`  on a two row 2D array.  You can get away with just using the definition of the L2-norm and you can vectorize that over matrices.

Comment: @rayryeng: Can you, please, show a bit of code on your idea?